# How to upload every file in directory to server with curl

Tags: terminal, ftp, curl

I have a local folder called `dist` and I would like to upload the files in that folder to my server - but I don't want to upload the folder - only it's contents

```
find dist -type f -exec curl -u username@my_server.com:my_password --ftp-create-dirs -T {} ftp://ftp.my_host.com/cantorah.com/ \;
```

This works but it results in a `dist` directory on my server - and I just want the files inside that directory to be uploaded without the directory itself.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why are you including `--ftp-create-dirs` if you don't wish to create directories?

Comment: *Do you have an answer to the question?* is rude @Anaksunaman is trying to help you figure that out.

Comment: For me it seems like @Anaksunaman already provided the answer by asking a question. I've clarified his perfectly valid comment by adding an answer formated as a declarative sentence instead.

Comment: So removing --ftp-create-dirs does work but the problem is that I have folders inside the 'dist' folder and I do want those folders to be preserved. Now - all the files are being copied and they all end up in the same root directory. How do I preserve the folder structure? So I do need to create some folders after all.

Comment: Select only the files inside the folder instead of the folder itself using `dist/*`.

Comment: When I do so, I receive the error message `curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553`. Any idea why?

Comment: You probably have to get rid of the `dist` in the `find` output. What about simple `cd dist ;  find * ...`?

Answer (score 2):

From the curl manpage:

> --create-dirs
>
> When used in conjunction with the -o, --output option, curl will create the necessary local directory hierarchy as needed. This option creates the >dirs mentioned with the -o, --output option,
> nothing else. If the --output file name uses no dir or if the >dirs it mentions already exist, no dir will be created.
>
> Created dirs are made with mode 0750 on unix style file systems.
>
> To create remote directories when using FTP or SFTP, try --ftp-create-dirs.

It seems like the --ftp-create-dirs parameter could lead to the unwanted behaviour of also creating a directory instead of only uploading the files.

You may consider running your above command **without** the --ftp-create-dirs option to achieve the wanted behavior.

Comment: So this does work but the problem is that I have folders inside the 'dist' folder and I do want those folders to be preserved. Now - all the files are being copied and they all end up in the same directory.

Comment: simply change your working directory `cd dist`